# How can I disable the connected edges gradient?

Tags: interface, vertices, edges

Whenever I select a vertex, Blender highlights all connected edges with orange gradient.  I find this super distracting and it's quite difficult to see complex vertex selections.

How can I disable the connected edges gradient?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (but I can be wrong) ... gradient indicates a connection, that is useful to see issue of dupli vertices at the same location or wanted splits of edge. If some blender user will see a vertex without gradients on edges will think it is a disconnected vertex. BTW your title is in opposite meaning than your description ... can you edit it?

Comment: @vklidu: yes, you are wrong ;)

Comment: @Chris ... sure you can change Theme ... but then you can't see selected edges when you switch to Edge Select Mode :) Only Active one ...

Answer (score 1):

Go to preferences -> Themes -> 3D Viewport -> Change Edge Select to black.

[image]

[image]